# How disable print function in iframe?

Tags: asp.net

May i know how disable print function in  iframe ? kindly advise thank you.

example i write  as below code statement, i need to disable print function and not allow to print out and read only.

```
<iframe
                    src="MKZHR-01-002(V000)%20.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;statusbar=0&amp;view=Fit;readonly=true; disableprint=true;"
                    width="1024" height="800" ></iframe>
```

Comment: i don't think you can disable the print function.

Comment: Any ideas to write it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using stylesheets:

At the top of your page, add:

```
<style>
@media print
  {
  iframe {display:none;}
  }
</style>
```

That should do it - this says that, if someone tries to print the page, the style should change so (all) iframes are not displayed.

Comment: HI, is it write as below @media print
  {
  iframe {display:none;}
  }<iframe
                    src="MKZHR-01-002(V000)%20.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;statusbar=0&amp;view=Fit;readonly=true; disableprint=true;"
                    width="1024" height="800" ></iframe>

Comment: No you would put the above code in your stylesheet - I have edited my post, to include the relevant tags. If you have a <head> tag on your page, put it immediately after that, otherwise, put it all the way at the start of the page.

Comment: i try it like this <style>@media print
  {
  iframe {display:none;}
  }
</style>
                  <iframe  
                        src="MKZHR-01-002(V000)%.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;statusbar=0&amp;view=Fit;readonly=true;" 
                        width="1024" height="800" ></iframe>

Comment: And when you try to print it, does it print the contents of the iframe?

Comment: Yes, it allow to print out

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable print.  Even if you managed to hide the print function in the browser, the client is still downloading the pdf and can print it by viewing it in a local viewer.

Even if you change the security settings of the pdf, that will prevent printing in some pdf viewers but not all--some ignore this setting and allow clients to print any document regardless of security settings.